# Flutter api request response body gives always instance of something

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API, when I do post requests, like this:

```
 await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }).then((value) => value.body);
```

it gives instance of etc. But If I print this **value.body**, then it gives json object, so I can see the values.

Now, since I can not see the values without print, I can not use in my futurebuilder. I want to get these values without print. Help please.

---

Future Builder code :
and,

```
final _postRequest = PostRequest()
      .postData(amount: state.amount.toInt(), maturity: state.maturity.toInt());
```

my _postRequest instance

```
 FutureBuilder(
                  future: _postRequest,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    print("ben snapshot datasıyım ${snapshot.data}");

                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          "Your Results",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                     
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
```

[image]

{"id":null,"amount":1000,"created_at":null,"client_id":null,"type":"0","maturity":19,"carCondition":null,"total_offers":8,"offers":[{"bank_id":400100099,"bank":"ING","interest_rate":1.79,"sponsored_rate":0,"bank_type":"ozel","url":"https://www.ing.com.tr/tr/sizin-icin/krediler/ihtiyac-kredisi-basvuru-formu","hypothec_fee":0,"expertise":0,"annual_rate":29.57512030367764},{"bank_id":400100032,"bank":"TEB","interest_rate":1.85,"sponsored_rate":0,"bank_type":"ozel","url":"https://www.cepteteb.com.tr/cepteteb-kredi-basvurusu?utm_source=teklifimgelsin&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=kredi","hypothec_fee":0,"expertise":0,"annual_rate":30.670908509091646},{"bank_id":400200010,"bank":"Ziraat","interest_rate":1.94,"sponsored_rate":0,"bank_type":"kamu","url":"https://www.ziraatbank.com.tr/tr/bireysel/basvurular/bireysel-kredi-basvurulari/tuketici-kredisi","hypothec_fee":0,"expertise":0,"annual_rate":32.33059049829124}]}

Comment: Can you share your `FutureBuilder` code?

Comment: shared in the above

Comment: Are you questioning about the `ben snapshot datasıyım null`?

Comment: ben snapshot datasıyım meaning I am the snapshot. Do not look it. Important thing is null section. _postRequest gives Instance of... and because of this snapshot is null

Comment: snapshot first gives null after that gives Instance of response. We need to see this instance of response's data

Comment: If you move the print after the conditional `if (!snapshot.hasData) {...}` and right before `return Column(...);`, it will not gives null.

Comment: after that it gives instance of ExampleResponse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241727/discussion-between-m-imam-pratama-and-efesahin).

Comment: we can not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "Whole" process, I found the solution in the DIO Package. Thanks to it. just do this:

```
    final response = await dio.post('/briefLoanOffer', data: {
      'amount': amount,
      'maturity': maturity,
      "type": type,
      "offer_count": offerCount
    });

    return response.data;
  }
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    });
```

use this website for convert json to dart class :
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

and then

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            Classname classinstance =
            Classname.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
   }
```

now you can access value from `classinstance` and like this `classinstance.data`

Comment: _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?')
I got this error, my body fields "a": 3 like this

Comment: @efesahin : seems to be you are parsing it to string instaed of int. Please reparse the response to class and check again

Comment: TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, dynamic>' it gives this, json decode

Comment: @efesahin : Please share json response here

Comment: I uploaded an img to above

Comment: need json string this will not work.

Comment: so what should I do, how can i use them into my future builder etc.

Comment: means you have to copy that response and post it here as from image not able to convert in dart file

Comment: I shared to above

Comment: can you use this class instead of yours : https://pastecode.io/s/y4vksmfn i have just parsed again

Comment: Now what should be the type? Future postData()... I have you know. Future<ExampleResponse> or Future<Offers>

Comment: ExampleResponse as you are using my given parsed class

Comment: TypeError (type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int?') >>>> sponsoredRate in the offers

Comment: I changed int to double but do not work, then it gives: required int, not double.

Comment: you can parse response again and check again

Comment: did you use same link?

Comment: yes i have use same one

Comment: Instance of 'ExampleResponse'
it gives. Btw I print like this:  final _postRequest = PostRequest()
      .postData(amount: state.amount.toInt(), maturity: state.maturity.toInt());
print(_postRequest);

Comment: You need to do like this :  var response  = await  PostRequest() .postData(amount: state.amount.toInt(), maturity: state.maturity.toInt()); print(response)